# My laptop is overheating and there is hot air coming out of it

Tags: laptop

There's hot air coming out of my laptop and I can't focus on my work
I have a HP laptop running windows and I've had it for almost two years.

Comment: Might be time to clean the dust out>>>https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01657439

Comment: Is it on your lap or on a table? Is the surface flat? Is there any dust or something bigger blocking the vents on both the bottom and sides of the laptop? Is your power profile set to 'Performance', with CPU over-clocked and fans set to max? Have you tried a balanced power profile?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop flash from raising my CPU temperature?](https://superuser.com/questions/43551/how-to-stop-flash-from-raising-my-cpu-temperature). But there are many more such posts.

Comment: Hot air coming out of your laptop is perfectly normal

Comment: @Ramhound - presumably this is "more than it used to" but we don't really have anything more to go on. I'd suggest taking it to a repair shop, rather than attempting a DIY fix, based on the tone of the question.