# Lenovo laptop : mode extreme performance

Tags: bios, performance, lenovo-laptop

Laptop Lenovo Ideapad 3 14ada05
Machine type model : 81W000HJPB

AMD Ryzen 5 3500U
AMD Radeon Vega 8 graphics

In bios i have the following option : intelligent cooling , battery saver , extreme performance.
At the moment i keep the laptop in intelligent cooling mode , but after two hours it heats up a lot.
( i mention that i don't play games but only office and internet browsing )

My question is i use it in extreme performance mode then the fan will start more often and will result in better cooling ?
( i know it will consume more battery faster , but most of the time the laptop is connected to a external monitor and i can charge so that the battery is full )
(task manager shows that vega 8 integrated graphics has 55 celsius degrees in idle ; normal should be 35 celsius degrees in idle ; test over 2 hours in idle )

I asked this question because i don't want to set the extreme performance mode and result in processor overclocking or TDP increase.
( or i'm wrong and nothing is overclocking ; the laptop is under warranty )

Comment: See the [IdeaPad 3-14ADA05 Laptop - Drivers & Software](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/fr/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/3-series/ideapad-3-14ada05/downloads/automatic-driver-update) for software and BIOS updates.

Comment: @harrymc i updated the bios and drivers to the latest version, but for software i don't want to install `lenovo thinkvantage tehnology` because i want to manually install my updates.

Comment: From the control panel i activated high performance mode and if i activate extreme performance from the bios the temperatures will be higher but the laptop will run without entering in cpu throttling ? One last question : it is normal for the laptop to idle reach 55-60 celsius degrees (intelligent cooling and high performance mode) ?

Comment: @harrymc i just bought the laptop and i can return it in a maximum of two weeks. The laptop runs very well but heats up a bit when not in use. The laptop has windows 10 21h1 installed and only two programs : libre office and adobe reader.

Comment: You should be able to trust your laptop to work correctly under any profile setting. Laptops have restricted airflow and temperatures will always be a little bit high. 55°C sounds like a normal target temperature to allow the CPU to run without the fan kicking in all the time, they like to keep things quiet. Unless you are experiencing overheating problems, i wouldnt worry too much. If you dont feel comfortable, try getting in touch with Lenovo support to ask your question directly to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all the software was updated, and as the laptop is new and its airways
do not need cleaning, it's probably working as well as can be expected.

The temperature of 55 Celsius is not worrisome at all.
Such a low temperature should not even cause any throttling.
You should only start getting worried when it nears 90 degrees.

Laptops, and especially the modern ultra-flat ones, will certainly have
worse heat problems than the old school laptops with larger fans.
This is normal and to be expected. If worried, you could contact
Lenovo Support for more information about your model.

For more information on laptop cooling see
[my answer](https://superuser.com/a/43555/8672).